# Elasticsearch: How can I filter & group by specific URL paths?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

I've got an index, urls, which looks like this:

```
path: {
   type: "string"
},
@timestamp: {
   type: "date",
   format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
},
```

The path will store the PATH section from a url, e.g:

```
https://facebook.com/profile/photos/album/1
```

Would be stored as:

```
/profile/photos/album/1
```

I'm storing all sorts of paths, so there could be more like:

```
/profile/photos/album/1
/profile/photos/album/2
/profile/photos/album/2
/profile/photos/album/2
/profile/friends/1
/profile/friends/2
/newsfeed/me/
/newsfeed/me/
/newsfeed/friendName/
```

I'm trying to find out the number of unique pageviews each of the paths have. I'm unsure how I should do this, should I use a regexp?

I'd imagine it'd look something like (pseudo code):

```
{
    "query": {
      "regexp": {
            "path": "" 
        },
        "unique": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out how to do this. I'm using the `aggs` method & using a regex to exclude results!

```
{
  "size": 0, // Don't return any _source results
  "aggs": {
    "path": { // This is the field that I'm 
      "terms": {
        "field": "path",
        "exclude": ".*(media|cache).*" // Add in the values here seper
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Breakdown:

1. path

   - Just the label of aggregation
2. field (path)

   - The field which I want to run the following regex on
3. exclude

   - Don't return documents where path has media or cache in it

I found this out from [Elasticsearch: Run aggregation on field & filter out specific values using a regexp not matching values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737104/elasticsearch-run-aggregation-on-field-filter-out-specific-values-using-a-reg/39737471#39737471)