# Elasticsearch: Run aggregation on field & filter out specific values using a regexp not matching values

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to run an aggregation on a field & ignore specific values! So I've got a field **path** that holds a heap of different url paths.

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "paths": {
            "terms":{
               "field": "path" // Count the no unique path ~> values
            }

      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": [
            {
               "regexp": {
                  // path MUST NOT CONTAIN media | cache
                  "path": {
                    "value": "(\/media\b|\bcache\b)"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

When running this, it doesn't filter out the documents which have a path that contains **cache or media**?!

If I remove  the **filter**, the same results would be returned if I left it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [excluding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) those values inside the terms aggregation like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "path",
        "exclude": ".*(media|cache).*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Caution:** From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax)

> Note: The performance of a regexp query heavily depends on the regular
>   expression chosen. Matching everything like .* is very slow as well as
>   using lookaround regular expressions. If possible, you should try to
>   use a long prefix before your regular expression starts

Another approach would be to get rid of those documents in query stage so you could move your filter to query and then aggregate on remaining results.

**EDIT** : With date filter

You could add date filter to query so that you would get only past day's results, something like this would work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "name_of_date_field": {
        "gte": "now-1d"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "path",
        "exclude": ".*(media|cache).*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's an idea. But this does the job really well :) I'm not worried about the performance as it's something that is triggered by a CRON and doesn't need to be quick!

Comment: Is it possible to add a date range filter as well? So I only get aggs from the previous day instead of my whole index?

Comment: I have added date filter to query, I hope it helps